# how to redirect to admin/login url after admin password reset in django

Tags: django, admin

In the project urls.py i have set these password reset url for forgot password.These url works fine .it resets the password but after reset completed in the login link , the login link redirects to the accounts/login url instead of admin/login url.How to redirect to admin/login url ??

> urls.py

```
                    path(  'admin/password_reset/',
                      auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(),
                      name='admin_password_reset',
                  ),
                  path(
                      'admin/password_reset/done/',
                      auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(),
                      name='password_reset_done',
                  ),
                  path(
                      'reset/<uidb64>/<token>/',
                      auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(),
                      name='password_reset_confirm',
                  ),
                  path(
                      'reset/done/',
                      auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(),
                      name='password_reset_complete',
                  ),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the path to the **`success_url`** argument

```
path(
        'reset/<uidb64>/<token>/',
        auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(success_url='/admin/login/'),
        name='password_reset_confirm',
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

```
url(r'^reset-password/$',
    PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='accounts/reset_password.html'),
    {
    'email_template_name': 'accounts/reset_password_email.html',
     'success_url' : reverse_lazy('accounts:reset_password_done')
     },
    name='reset_password')
```